# Unable to Import Protractor in TypeScript App

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am unable to import protractor in my TypeScript application...

```
import { browser } from "protractor";
```

I receive the error:

> Cannot find module 'protractor' ts2307

[Image of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqdr5.png)

Comment: can you share your package.json at all as this is likely to be important to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add dependies in your package.json (To add package.json file in your project
run command in the terminal or command prompt

```
 npm init
```

after this command, some question will be asked like

```
{
  "name": "newprotractor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
```

after giving details, file be created and then add some dependencies like protractor, typescript

```
"dependencies": {
 "protractor": "^5.4.2",
}
```

then you will not get any error

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project folder

First run  `npm i protractor --save-dev`.

Run `npm i` from your project folder that conatains the `package.json`. // To download all the required libraries

Hope it helps you

Comment: why we need to download all protractor libraries??

Comment: @Avi `browser` can be imported from `protractor` only if its libraries are downloaded